# Scala Performance Issue with mutable List (LinkedList)

Tags: scala

I have the following code snippets:  The code reads the system (Linux) dictionary(en) file and keeps it in memory List.

**Code 1 : (With mutable List)**

```
  val word = scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[String]("init");

  for(line <- Source.fromFile("/usr/share/dict/words").getLines()){
    val s : String = line.trim()

    if( // some checks
    ){
      word append scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[String](s) 
    }

  }
```

**Code 2 : (With Immutable List)**

```
var word = List[String]()

  for(line <- Source.fromFile("/usr/share/dict/words").getLines()){
    val s : String = line.trim()

    if( // some checks
    ){
      word ::= s
    }

  }
```

Code 2 : returns almost immediately , But
Code 1 : Takes for ever .

Can any one help me out , why is it taking so much time for mutable List? . Should we use Mutable at all or Am I doing something wrong?

Scala version used : 2.10.3

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Comment: imho: you convert every line of your file to a linked list before appending. that might take some time. so your in effect not comparing immutable vs mutable. youre comparing immutable list with a mutable linked list.

Comment: LinkedList does not allow you to add single element only as LinkedList.

Answer (score 1):

```
word append scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[String](s)
```

Traverse the `word` list and then at the end append the items from the other list.

```
word ::= s
```

Append `s` at the front of the word list and assign the new list to word variable.

Appending to the end of list is always expensive as compared to add a item to the front.

Comment: LinkedList should be the easiest when it comes to appending right? (only next pointer swap) . why is is traversing the entire List . What method we should use instead of update?

Comment: @user2699692 They might be 'easy' if the list is keeping the reference to its last element. If it's not, you have to traverse the full list every time to get to the end and *then* append. Compare that to prepending, which has constant time complexity...

Comment: Thanks , guys . 
Changing update to insert method did the trick . Even though LinkedList has last pointer , it traverses the List to get the last pointer for append.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you are adding to the end of a list repeatedly (append).  This takes time on the order of the length of the list. In the second example, you are adding to the beginning of a list (::).  This takes constant time.  So the first example has an execution time that increases with the square of the number of lines in the file, and the second has an execution time that increases linearly with the length of the file.

This is due to the nature of linked lists, which are the data structure underlying both immutable `List` and mutable `LinkedList`.  linked lists are fast to access at the front and slow to access at the back.

Comment: FYI can make this an entirely immutable statement with no particular loss to efficiency: `val word = (Source fromFile "/usr/share/dict/words").getLines() map (_ trim) filter (_ > "alligator")`

Comment: where `> "alligator"` is a stand-in for your "some checks" comment